# Recoger url del post en wordpress

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, wordpress, wordpress-plugin

1. Cuando el usuaro entra a editar/crear un post mediante el admin de Wordpress se crea el metabox `labur_add_metabox` el cual contiene un `input de tipo text` vació y un botón.
2. También se ejecuta la acción `labur_init` en la cual se registra un fichero js (`labur.js`).
3. El fichero `labur.js` se ejecuta cuando el usuario hace click sobre el botón `id=button_labur_get_url`
4. Desde `labur.js` se ejecuta la función `labur_get_url_process` la cual debe de recoger la url del post actual y devolversela al fichero js.

Código de labur.php

```
//show metabox in post editing page
add_action('add_meta_boxes', 'labur_add_metabox' ); // Creación de metabox personlaizado

//load external files
add_action( 'add_meta_boxes', 'labur_init' ); // 'add_meta_boxes' tal vez no sea correcto. Tal vez sea mas correcto otro Hook

// add admin settings
add_action('wp_ajax_labur_get_url', 'labur_get_url_process'); // El prefijo wp_ajax es por convención de wordpress


// Función para procesar el AJAX
function labur_get_url_process() {
  global $post;
  echo get_permalink( $post->ID );
}

/**
 * load external files
 */
function labur_init() {
    //register plugin js file. Jquery is a requirement for this script so we specify it
    wp_register_script( 'labur-js', plugins_url( '/labur.js', __FILE__ ), array('jquery') );

    //load scripts
    wp_enqueue_script('jquery'); 
    wp_enqueue_script('labur-js'); 

}

function labur_add_metabox() {
    //doc http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_meta_box
    add_meta_box('labur_url', 'Bidalketaren labur.eus helbidea','labur_url_handler', 'post', 'side', 'high'); 
}

/**
 * metabox handler
 */
function labur_url_handler() {
    echo '<input type="text" id="labur_shortened_url" name="labur_direccion" readonly />';
    echo '<p class="submit"><input id="button_labur_get_url" class="button button-primary button-large" name="labur_url" value="Sortu labur helbidea" type="button"/></p>';
}
```

Código de `labur.js`

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    jQuery("#button_labur_get_url").click(function(){
    var url = document.location.protocol+'//'+document.location.host+'/aldakurnet/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php';
    jQuery.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: url,
            dataType: 'text',
            data: {
                action: 'labur_get_url', // Ejecuta labur_get_url_process
            },
            success: function(data, textStatus, XMLHttpRequest){
                $('#labur_shortened_url').val(data);
            },
            error: function(MLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown){
                alert(errorThrown);
            }
        });
    });
});
```

`labur_get_url_process` devuleve 0

Comment: Todo muy bien expuesto, realmente ejemplar. Pero... ¿Cuál es la pregunta? ¿Cuál es el error? ¿Cuál es el problema? ¿Qué es lo que no está funcionando?

Comment: Que la función `labur_get_url_process` devuelve el valor `0`. No me devuelve la url del post

Comment: Si estás dentro del Loop, puedes obtenerlo con esto sencillamente: `the_permalink();` pues ya WP conoce todo de tu post. Si estás fuera del loop entonces sí debes pasarle el id.

Comment: ni `the_permalink()` ni como puse en el post `global $post;
  echo get_permalink( $post->ID );` funcionan. Por si sirve de ayuda, labur.php es un plugin que estoy desarrollando.

Comment: ¿Puedes por favor poner esto: `echo "**prueba**".the_permalink();` en la función `labur_get_url_process()` omitiendo todo lo demás y comentar lo que ocurre?

Comment: Devuelve `**prueba**`

Comment: Da la impresión de que tampoco reconoce la variable $post. Prueba si es así con un print_r($post); y también echo $post->ID;

Comment: Creo que si usas el código como indica WP dentro del loop debería funcionar siempre y cuando haya posts en tu instalación WP. Aquí tienes un ejemplo: https://codex.wordpress.org/The_Loop preguntando if have_posts()...

Comment: Sí el problema es el que dices. No reconoce la variable $post. No estoy en un `loop` porque estoy en la zona de administración del blog. En la edición del post. Es decir, estoy fuera del `loop` y se supone que para esos casos debería de funcionar `global $post;` pero no funciona dentro de `labur_get_url_process()`. En cambio haciendo pruebas si funciona dentro de `labur_init()` . No sé cual es el motivo y no logro la solución.

Comment: Dichas funciones son para usar dentro de un post específico. ¿No puedes probar el plugin yendo a un post? No sé si esta otra función pueda servirte: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_post_permalink/

Comment: `get_post_permalink()` me devuelve la url de wordpress. En este caso `http://localhost/aldakurnet` pero no consigo la url especifica del post

Comment: _pero no consigo la url especifica del post_ Es que no entiendo. Si entras a dicho post debería funcionarte de una de las dos maneras ya citadas, sea con `the_permalink()` sea con `get_permalink()`. Si el plugin está hecho para funcionar dentro de los posts, el lugar para probarlo es entrando en los posts.

Comment: Si escribo `echo get_permalink(1);` me devuelve la url perfectamente. El problema es que `echo get_permalink($post->ID)` no funciona

Comment: `get_permalink($post->ID)` está pensado para un entorno dinámico en el cual tomará el ID del post actual y te devolverá su permalink, imagino que eso es lo que quieres hacer con el plugin. Si quieres que el plugin funcione para un solo post entonces le puedes pasar manualmente el id del post del cual quieres el permalink. Hecho de forma dinámica te deberá funcionar. De hecho, si instalas, activas y pruebas el plugin con algún post no creo que tengas problemas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

La solución pasa utilizando `isset`en `labur_get_url_process`

1. `labur_ìnit` Envía al `labur.js`un objeto `Ajax` con el `post_id`y la `action` a ejecutar.
2. El `labur.js`recibe los parámetros y ejecuta `labur_get_url_process` para después escribir el resultado en un `input` con `id=labur_shortened_url`

Código de labur.php:

```
<?php

//show metabox in post editing page
add_action('add_meta_boxes', 'labur_add_metabox' ); // Creación de metabox personlaizado

//load external files
add_action( 'add_meta_boxes', 'labur_init' ); 

// add admin settings
add_action('wp_ajax_labur_get_url', 'labur_get_url_process'); // El prefijo wp_ajax es por convención de wordpress



// Función para procesar el AJAX
function labur_get_url_process() {
    if(isset($_POST['postID'])) 
    {
      $post_id = $_POST['postID'];
      $post_url = get_permalink($post_id);
      echo $post_url;
    }

    exit();
}

/**
 * load external files
 */
function labur_init() {
    //register plugin js file. Jquery is a requirement for this script so we specify it
    wp_register_script( 'labur-js', plugins_url( '/labur.js', __FILE__ ), array('jquery') ); 
    //load scripts
    wp_enqueue_script('jquery'); 
    wp_enqueue_script('labur-js'); 

    global $post;
    $post_id = $post->ID;
    wp_localize_script('labur-js', 'MyAjax', array(
      'post_id' => $post_id,
      'action'=> 'labur_get_url' // labur_get_url es la acción pero sin el prefijo wp_ajax. Esta acción ejecutará la función labur_get_url_process
    ));

}

?>
```

Código `labur.js`

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    jQuery("#button_labur_get_url").click(function(){
    var url = document.location.protocol+'//'+document.location.host+'/aldakurnet/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php';
    jQuery.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: url,
            dataType: 'text',

            data: {
                postID: MyAjax.post_id, 
                action: MyAjax.action 
            },
            success: function(data, textStatus, XMLHttpRequest){
                $('#labur_shortened_url').val(data);
            },
            error: function(MLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown){
                alert(errorThrown);
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Si estas en la sección de administración de Wordpress no debes usar $post->ID sino **$_REQUEST["post"]**.

El $post->ID se usa siempre y cuando $post este cargado con el elemento generado por otras funciones como wp_query o get_posts.

Comment: Sí, exactamente estoy en el area de administración. Que obtendre exactamente en $_REQUEST["post"] . Luego Cómo consigo la url del post en cuestion?

Comment: con $_REQUEST["post] obtenes el ID del post que estas editando (numero). para obtener la url del post tenes que obtenerlo con la función que ya estabas usando $url_del_post = get_permalink($_REQUEST["post"]);

Comment: No funciona. No sé el motivo pero las variables globales y demás no funcionan dentro de la función que procesa el ajax `labur_get_url_process`